# Pull search result from LinkedIn using html agility pack

Tags: c#, html, linkedin-api, html-agility-pack

I want to pull the top search result for a LinkedIn query.

In this fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vtwi7g

passing to 'html' var this link :
https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=firstname%3Ajohn%20AND%20lastname%3Adoe%20AND%20company%3Amicrosoft%20AND%20title%3Aceo&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER

I want to get first result : 
https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe-63803769/

- I guess the program needs some credentials to log in to LinkedIn first - how do I pass these ?
- I tried Inspect element to see its location - how to traverse the DOM to get the first result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be more complicated with linked in search. Their search closed for unauthorized users.

First of all you need to login with your browser and then take your session cookies `li_at` and `_lipt`.

LinkedIn is not rendering results list directly to html markup. He is rendering big json objects into `<code>` element and then using JS to render that.

Your console app should be like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var html = @"https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/index/?keywords=firstname%3Ajohn%20AND%20lastname%3Adoe%20AND%20company%3Amicrosoft%20AND%20title%3Aceo&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER";

    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    web.PreRequest = new HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(OnPreRequest2);
    var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

    var codeElement = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//code[starts-with(@id,'bpr-guid')][last()]");
    var json = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(codeElement.Last().InnerText);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
    var profiles = obj.included.Where(i => i.firstName != null);
    foreach(var profile in profiles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Profile Name: " + profile.firstName + ";" + profile.lastName + ";" + profile.occupation + ";https://www.linkedin.com/in/" + profile.publicIdentifier); 
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
public static bool OnPreRequest2(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    var cookies =   "li_at={YOURCOOKIEHERE};" +
                    "_lipt={YOURCOOKIEHERE}";
    request.Headers.Add(@"cookie:" + cookies);
    return true;
}


public class Rootobject
{
    public Included[] included { get; set; }
}


public class Included
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string occupation { get; set; }
    public string objectUrn { get; set; }
    public string publicIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

At the end it will print

```
Profile Name: John;Doe;ceo at Microsoft;https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe-8102b868
Profile Name: John;Doe;Ceo at Microsoft;https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe-63803769
Profile Name: John;Doe;CEO at Microsoft;https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe-2151b69b
```

Comment: I installed html agility pack, but get build errors - JsonConvert, HttpWebRequest, WebUtility do not exist , No overload for OnPreRequest2 matches ..PreRequestHandler - which other namespaces should I include ?

Comment: nvm, I had to install NewtonSoft.Json version 9, since 10 doesn't work with VS2012.. btw, I have an other simple requirement - to read the html search variable from a file/table and to dump the output to a file/table. Would you be interested in coding this for a $25 amazon gift card ?